# how to return computed html in vue2?

Tags: dom, vue.js, vue-component, virtual-dom

I try to return the part of html depending on variable type I want to do like：

```
<template>
   <div>{{getvalue(this.$store.state.output)}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
methods:{
   getvalue(output){
       if(output.constructor == Array){
         re="";
         for(i in output){
             re+=<p>{{i}}</p>;
         }
         return re;
       }
       else if(output.constructor == Object){
           re="";
           for(i in output){
              re+=<p><span>i</span><span>{{output[i]}}</span></p>
           }
          return re;
       }else if(output.constructor == String){
          return <p>{{output}}</p>
       }
   } 
},
...
}
</script>
```

I know in react I can use virtualDOM to do that， how should I do the similar things like above in Vue2.5.11?

Comment: As a general rule, you don't. It's missing the whole point of Vue.

Answer (score 0):

@ceejayoz is right. It would be missing the whole point of Vue.

Another mistake is that computed values don't accept parameters. It is supposed to be treated as a value and not a function.

This is a more proper way of doing things in Vue. By using `v-if` and `v-for`.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="getOutputConstructor==Array">
            <p v-for="i in this.$store.state.output" :key="i">{{i}}</p>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="getOutputConstructor==Object">
            ...
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="getOutputConstructor==String">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    getOutputConstructor() {
      const output = this.$store.state.output;
      return output.constructor;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

But.. if you really really want to do it the wrong way, use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: Can I use methods instead of computed?

Comment: Yes you can    if u insist